# Content from Website to iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql, ios

I've been creating iPhone applications for the past couple of months, and one question has always crossed my mind: how does one go about creating an app like Instagram or some other application that lets users sign up and log in? I know how to do this with a website (SQL), but how do you do it on the iPhone? General answers are perfectly fine. Thanks!

Comment: there's something called "google" try to use this...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach: use UIWebView to wrap the website.
If you prefer using native UI, you can use JSON to communicate with the server for user login part.